# RN 0.63 support iOS ProMotion?

Tags: ios, react-native

Does RN support iOS ProMotion for faster refresh rates without having to add some codes?

I remember that several months ago when our team released the iOS app which is built by RN it do support ProMotion, but last week when I open the app I found the promotion didn't work anymore. We didn't change any code for refresh rate. Did anything changed by iOS new version?

Thank you for any comments.

Comment: Why are you using RN 0.63? That is a very old version which is not being actively developed.

Comment: Actually we are using 0.64 which is also very old. Does the latest version support iOS promotion by nature?